# Mixed Hodge structures on (infinite) covers of complex varieties?

Tags: complex-manifolds, covering-spaces, mixed-hodge-structure

Let $X$ be a complex variety, and let $\tilde{X}\to X$ be a covering map. Does the singular cohomology $H_\ast(\tilde{X};\mathbb{Z})$ carry a natural mixed Hodge structure?

If the cover is finite, then $\tilde{X}$ is also a complex variety (by generalized Riemann existence), so the answer is yes.  I'm hoping to understand what we can say for infinite sheeted covers, perhaps under some 'niceness' assumptions on $X$, e.g. $X$ is smooth (for the examples I'm interested in, I cannot take $X$ compact).

If the answer in general is no, is there a natural class of counterexamples?  Are there reasonable assumptions we can put on $X$ that fix these?

Comment: What about the infinite-genus surface as a cover of a finite-genus one? In this case $H_1$ is infinitely generated.

Comment: Technically, there is nothing that prevents a mixed hodge structure from being infinitely generated. But I would worry about examples like $\mathbb C/ \mathbb Z \to \mathbb C/\mathbb Z^2$ which maps $\mathbb G_m$ to an elliptic curve. Should this map be compatible with Hodge structures?  In a $p$-adic analytic setting, this sort of example is OK-- i.e. the  map on etale cohomology is compatible with Galois representations, so perhaps there is something one can say.

Comment: Also, if you haven't seen it already, this paper seems relevant. 
 https://www.math.ucla.edu/~totaro/papers/public_html/sing.pdf

Comment: @PhilTosteson, thanks for the reference.  Theorem 2.2 of Totaro's talk is especially relevant (I'd remembered some inkling of this, maybe from the last time I looked over Totaro, but it's nice to have it clearly stated).

Comment: @PhilTosteson, your example with $\mathbb{G}_m$ mapping to an elliptic curve is actually quite close to the type of examples I'm interested in (the difference being that my infinite covers are not in general algebraic). For $X_\Gamma$ a Shimura variety, with Hermitian locally symmetric space $\mathcal{X}$, let $\Gamma'\subset \Gamma$ be a lattice of lower rank. Then I'm interested in finite etale maps over $\mathcal{X}/\Gamma'$ (and really only those that are pullbacks of finite etale maps over $X_\Gamma$).

Comment: 1. Hodge structures are only for algebraic varieties, not analytic varieties, so it has to depend on the pair $(Y\to X)$. 2. Not every cover works; eg, a $\mathbb Z$ cover of an elliptic curve has no compatible Hodge structure. 3. But some covers are OK, such as the cover corresponding to a map to a semiabelian variety. This is only for normal subgroups and heads in a nilpotent direction. See Richard Hain, [eg, this](https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9403015). 4. Your case sounds tough. If your sublattice is Shimura, just use that Shimura variety as a proxy and if it isn't, I'm skeptical.

Comment: @BenWieland, could you explain a little more what you mean by "Hodge structures are only for algebraic varieties"?  The original examples are compact complex manifolds, and as Totaro notes in his ICM talk, once you have resolution of singularities (due to Guillen-Navarro-Aznar), you get weights on the de Rham cohomology of any compact analytic space, by the same argument Deligne uses in the algebraic case.

Comment: Hodge structures are for complete varieties. Algebraic varieties have essentially unique completions, thus Hodge structures. Analytic varieties do not. An infinite cover of an algebraic variety does not have a chosen completion and thus does not have a Hodge structure. If you want to assign it a Hodge structure, it will have to depend on the variety downstairs having a Hodge structure. But an analytic variety with a chosen completion is fine.

Comment: @BenWieland, thanks for clarifying.  Now I'm more on board, though I'd say it's more correct to say that Hodge structures are for complex analytic spaces with an equivalence class of compactifications. For algebraic varieties or compact spaces, there is a unique equivalence class.  For others, not so much.  But, one could imagine that given a cover of an algebraic variety, there might be some natural compactification, bootstrapping from the compactification downstairs.  This is what Phil's comments and Totaro's paper helped me explore in my examples.

Comment: Since the compactification upstairs does not map to the compactification downstairs (consider the case that downstairs is already compact!), there is no reason to think it relevant. Again, consider a $\mathbb Z$ cover of an elliptic curve. There is a unique compactification, but no Hodge structure can be compatible with the map, not that one nor any other. Similarly, Schottky uniformization. The Hain link I gave above was about Torelli space, which has no compactification, not being homotopy equivalent to a finite complex. I think that is typical of useful examples.